# How to get listitem which was clicked?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, contextmenu

I made a contextMenu for my list. Then i have a function like this for code:

```
lmi5.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, function(e:ContextMenuEvent){

});
```

How can i get to know which listItem was clicked?

I was hoping that the "e.mouseTarget" would be an item, but its a list's CellRenderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

The ´e.mouseTarget´ is not the selected item in the context menu, but the display element on which you right-clicked. I guess you need to add one different event listener function to each item in the context menu, this way you can tell which one of them was clicked, for example:

```
var myContextMenu:ContextMenu new ContextMenu();
var item:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("item 1");
var item2:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("item 2");

myContextMenu.customItems.push(item);
myContextMenu.customItems.push(item2);

item1.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, item1_select_handler);
item2.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, item2_select_handler);

function item1_select_handler(e:ContextMenuEvent):void
{
  trace("item 1!!");
}

function item2_select_handler(e:ContextMenuEvent):void
{
  trace("item 2!!");
}
```

Comment: Oh, you wrote "e.mouseMenu", i guess that was a typo... Anyways, I was wrong, the ´e.mouseTarget´ then is not the item in the context menu, but the display element on which you right-clicked. What is `lmi5`in your bit of code? You should add different ´ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT´ event listener to each item of the contextMenu, not to the context menu itself. I'll update my answer right now with working code.

Comment: oops, it was a typo. I understand what you are suggestion, but this method isnt completelly safe and i will have to write a lot of addition code(since when i press right button on some item, its not selected, it only was when i had the cursor over it). Im still hoping theres a way to get coordinates of contextmenu click and transform this into an item under it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var l:Object=(e.mouseTarget).data
```

This will give you the data contained in the cellRenderer

Comment: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property data through a reference with static type flash.display:InteractiveObject.